# Text Processing - How to output file that match a pattern in all of its line

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have this `file.txt` containing this list.

```
LIST: ACCEPTED - rfhfui4fuw3hjnf43.4fj9u8fhjkszdnvckizfjh489.dfsdf
LIST: ACCEPTED - rfhfui4fuw3hjnf43.fj9u8fhjkszdnvckizfjh489.dfsdf
LIST: ACCEPTED - rfhfui4fuw3hjnf43.4fj9u8fhjkszdnvckizfjh489.dfsdf
LIST: ACCEPTED - rfhfui4fuw3hjnf43.4f.j9u8fhjkszdnv.ckizfjh489.dfsdf
LIST: ACCEPTED - rfhfui4fuw3hjnf.43.4fj9u8fhjkszdnvckizfjh489.dfsdf
```

What I want to happen is to know if `file.txt` has all the lines match a pattern I want to find.

E.g. If the pattern `ACCEPTED` has match all lines of `file.txt` then `echo "All lines are Accepted"`.

I think `grep` has the answer to this but I'm still experimenting and still no luck.

I want to use this with an `if...else` condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That boils down to finding at least one line that doesn't match the pattern, so:

```
if [ ! -s file ] || [ ! -r file ] || grep -qv ACCEPTED file; then
  echo file is empty, not readable or has at least one line without ACCEPTED
else
  echo "all of file's lines have ACCEPTED"
fi
```

The `[ ! -s file ]` assumes the `file` is a regular file (it checks the size of the file which for some other types of files like fifo, devices on some systems like Linux can be 0 even though the file contains data).

With `awk`:

```
if awk '!/ACCEPTED/{exit 1}; END {if (!NR) exit 1}' < file; then
   echo "all of file's lines have ACCEPTED"
fi
```

To find those (regular) files that have *ACCEPTED* on all their lines:

```
find . -type f -size +0 -readable ! -exec grep -vq ACCEPTED {} \; -print
```

(`-readable` not available in all `find` implementation)